# Docker: Error: Could not find certificate cert.pem?

Tags: docker, ssl, virtualbox, devops, docker-machine

and thank you in advance for your precious time.

I spent my whole day figuring out what is wrong with my configuration. For all I could gather, here is the issue I am facing.

I Operate on MacOS Catalina 10.15.4, 2.6 GHz 6-Core Intel Core i7.

I used to run the command `docker image build -t myContainer .` to  build my container, and followed by `docker run -p 5000:5000 myContainer` to run my container. 
It used to run flawlessly, until I opened the Docker Desktop, and deleted my containers from there. I suspect, the moment I did that, I was able to execute the `docker run` command, followed by the following error.

> `Error: Could not find certificate cert.pem`

Though, I was able to build my containers successfully.

The step I took to try to tackle with this problem are as follows, but didn't work. These might be helpful to understand the issue more clearly.

1. I tried to regenerate the certificates for my default machine using `docker-machine regenerate-certs default` followed by `eval $(docker-machine env default)`. Although it did regenerate my certificates, but still could not solve the error while running the `docker run -p 5000:5000 myContainer` command.
2. I restarted my docker machine using `docker-machine restart default`, still didn't help
3. I deleted the default machine using `docker-machine rm default`, and then again created the default machine using `docker-machine create -d virtualbox default'
4. I deleted and cleaned docker from my system using `brew cask uninstall docker` and then downloaded the docker.dmg from the website. I restarted my laptop, and started building by container again. build was successful as usual, but it still threw the `Error: Could not find certificate cert.pem`
5. I did ssh into default docker machine created symlink for cert.pem from `/User/manjot/.docker/machone/machines/default/cert.pem` to `/var/lib/boot2docker/cert.pem` considering the docker was missing the cert.pem in that folder. But still it did not solve the issue.
6. I also tried to clear the **DOCKER_*** variables from my environment, and reset them as per the default container using `eval $(docker-machine env default)`.[image]
7. I also override the certificates adding following to daemon.json

```
{
  "insecure-registries" : ["myregistrydomain.com:5000"]
}
```

I could not figure out that **Where is the docker trying to find the path to the cert.pem?**

I also tried to run these commands as sudo. I also removed the containers and default docker machine from user `manjotsingh` and created a docker using root. But still it did not work

Comment: Just an update, updating the docker desktop to v2.2.0.5 fixed this issue for me.